# Is there alternative to GitLab's Protected environments?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

[Protected environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#protecting-manual-jobs) are available only on premium tier. Are there any alternatives to use on free? I've been researching this topic for a while and for now I have one idea - use [multi-project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html). But this solution adds a little too much complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hence my goal was to restrict running manual jobs on pipelines for users  - I have found that [protected branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html) and protected variables will be the best solution I have so far.

Then just restrict who can merge/push co protected branches and automatically only those people will be able to trigger manual jobs in those branches.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to at least mimic protected environments a bit.

- Create a repo with only the deploy job in its gitlab-ci.yml.
- In your job which you want to be protected call the pipeline in the above repo with a [multi-project-pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html#multi-project-pipelines)
- Only grant certain users developer/maintainer access to your protected repo
- Only users with access to the protected repo can now run the manual job, all other users will get an error

```
deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    project: group/protected-repo
    strategy: depend
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://example.com
  when: manual
  only:
     - master
```

Comment: I was considering this solution, but as mentioned in a question - it adds a little bit overhead. To be clear - I need some variables in current pipeline I had to pass to another.